# Ants on Zucchini flowers

Tags: pests

I've noticed a lot of ants on my zucchini plants and in particular the flowers. Not sure whether this is an issue I should be concerned about and if so what could be done to manage them. [image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem, the ants are attracted by the sweet pollen. They won't eat the plant or harm it what so ever. Keep an eye out on aphids though, ants seem to pet them like cattle (milk them), so check if they are not sucking on leaves somewhere. If not, only ants on flowers is nothing to worry about.